# asp:HiddenField being cached server-side somewhere?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms, iis

I have two ASPX pages; they use the same DLL and class, so the first line of each file looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="CustomPageCode.CustomPage" %>
```

(maybe this is bad form to have two *.aspx pages sharing the same codebehind, but I don't want to have two separate classes with identical code)

I'm 'configuring' each page through a hidden field --
`Page1.aspx` has the line:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="DepartmentName" value="DepartmentOne" runat="server" />
```

and `Page2.aspx` has the line:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="DepartmentName" value="DepartmentTwo" runat="server" />
```

My CodeBehind reads `DepartmentName.Value` to do a bunch of codebehind things, like SQL queries, based on the value of the HiddenField specific to each department, and also Javascript reads that value to do department-specific things as well.  I'm doing it this way to simplify configuring each page -- the way the page is configured is right there in the ASPX page and the same value is visible to both ASPX and Javascript.

However, if either page does a `POST` event -- now `DepartmentName.Value` ONLY returns the value from the page that did the POST for any page with the same codebehind.  `Page1.ASPX`, even though the `asp:HiddenField` value in the source is still clearly "`DepartmentOne`", if `Page2.ASPX` did the POST, `DepartmentName.Value` will be "`DepartmentTwo`" regardless of which page is opened.

The funky thing is: if I open the same page in Chrome, Page One will still have Page Two's `DepartmentName.Value`, even if the POST event never occurred in Chrome; clearing the IE cache doesn't fix it either.  This is definitely something happening on the server side, getting cached somewhere.  An IIS reset resolves it.

Google has told me that ASP.NET caches a bunch of things from a POST event but doesn't exactly say how it's handled, or how to enable/disable it, or which of the many cache locations it is located in, and many examples look like I'd have to specifically tell it to start caching things in a persistent way.  The closest thing I've found is `ModelState.Clear();` in a `!IsPostBack` at the beginning of the `Page_Load`, but that doesn't resolve it, I'm not using MVC in my code as far as I know.

So, my question is, how do I force that the GET uses the hidden value in the source code, and not some cached value from an old POST event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my problem:

After wrestling with ViewState, it turns out my problem wasn't hidden fields being cached, it was what was being done with the hidden fields.

At the beginning of my class, I have a variable:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ThisDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

that my code uses `ThisDictionary.Add()` to add values from ASPX hidden fields to --  but I never declared `ThisDictionary` as 'new' in my actual function, so every time I added an element to the Dictionary of hidden fields, it was persistent *across multiple pages using the same class*.

So, when I load my values from what I think is the hidden field, the codebehind is reading the hidden field correctly, but when it takes action in C#, it is using the data in the Dictionary with a bunch of other pages' data in it, hence the appearance that hidden field values are being cached somewhere.

By adding a statement to declare it as a `new Dictionary<string,string>()` at the beginning of my `Page_Load` function, it now wipes the dictionary clean with each page load and now it's behaving how I would expect, containing only values from the hidden fields on the particular page.

(I acknowledge what I should probably do is have a separate class with these variables in it, rather than lumping it all into the main ASPX class that gets called when the page loads.  Something for the next version)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably [ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx), but I'd have to see more of your code for this to be more than a wild guess. I do see this:

> I don't want to have two separate classes with identical code)

Yep, that's a good thing. But it sounds like maybe you have too much code in the page class itself that should be moved to a separate utility class, where two separate pages can now share that same utility code. Alternatively, you want a *single* `Department.aspx` page that takes a URL argument, like this:  `/Department.aspx?deptid=Department1` or `/Department.aspx?deptID=Department2`

Then key off of the url argument, rather than a hidden field. If you don't like the ugly URL, you can use [routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx) to get prettier URLs like this: `/Departments/Department1` or `/Departmennts/Department2`